# Highlighting the category column in time series data in plotly as shades

Tags: python, visualization, plotly-python, timeserieschart

here i have a time series data , i am trying to plot using plotly as reproduced . i have a categorical columns `fill_cat` which is binary 1 or 0 respectively . where ever 1 exist a vertical lines or shade should be plotted to identify there was some event 1.

[image: Glimpse of Data set]

[image: Expected visualisation]

```
 import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import datetime

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

# data sample
nperiods = 200
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 12, size=(nperiods, 4)),
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
datelist = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),periods=nperiods).tolist()
df['dates'] = datelist 
df = df.set_index(['dates'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.iloc[0] = 0
df = df.cumsum().reset_index()
df['fill_cat'] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0] 
df.head()

fig = px.line(df, x='dates', y=df.columns[1:])
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='rgba(0,0,255,0.1)')
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='rgba(0,0,255,0.1)')
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers were prepared using the official reference. Adding a rectangle on a graph can be handled by `add_vrect()`. If it becomes an interval with a manual start and end, you can color it in, but the approach I took was to use a looping process for the data frames extracted by 'fii_cat'. (It's on a daily basis) I think that's the effect. Fill colors are not enabled.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import datetime

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

# data sample
nperiods = 200
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(-10, 12, size=(nperiods, 4)),
                  columns=list('ABCD'))
datelist = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),periods=nperiods).tolist()
df['dates'] = datelist 
df = df.set_index(['dates'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.iloc[0] = 0
df = df.cumsum().reset_index()
df['fill_cat'] = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0] 
df.head()


fig = px.line(df, x='dates', y=df.columns[1:])
fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='rgba(0,0,255,0.1)')
fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=True, gridwidth=1, gridcolor='rgba(0,0,255,0.1)')

fill_data = df[df['fill_cat'] == 1]
for idx,row in fill_data.iterrows():
    d = str(row.dates.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
    fig.add_vrect(x0=str(row.dates.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),
                  x1=str(row.dates.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')),
                  fillcolor='yellow',
                  opacity=0.5,
                  line_width=2)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'add_vrect'` getting this error

Comment: Updated to all codes that created the graph. You can now check it out.